# GetComponent<Renderer>() returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access the Mesh Renderer of my barrel objects. In the Unity player, everythinks works fine, but when creating builds i get a nullreference when trying to access the Renderer of my Barrel gameobjects. The tags in my scene are correct. The weird thing is that the Renderer of oil works fine. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Also, there's no other object that has the tag "barrel". I checked the return values of GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel"))

Update:

I logged the components of the barrel Gameobject,
and the meshRenderer is not listed, i don't have a clue why though

```
private void EvaluateDissolve()
{
    foreach (GameObject gobj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("oil"))
    {
        gobj.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_SliceAmount",m_dissolveFactor + 0.2f);
    }

    foreach (GameObject gobj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel"))
    {
        if (gobj.GetComponent<Renderer>() == null)
            Debug.Log("Renderer is null");

        gobj.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_SliceAmount",m_dissolveFactor);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are your barrels active on the scene when you are calling `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`?

Comment: i just doublechecked, they are active

Comment: why no try first to fill your array and use later?
GameObjects[] gobjs; 
gobjs =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel");

Comment: Have you attempted to get the MeshRenderer component instead of the more generic Renderer component which you are trying to get now?

Comment: no, but the oil object has a meshrenderer too, and this works...

Comment: i tried it, no effect